# Flush / save only the selected language of the user and not other changes

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

On my JSF application I have a a button for the user to switch the language of the application between English and German.
The changed language has to be saved to the user table in the database.

The problem is, if the user changes the language during he works with the application where he can modify some data all changes will automatically flushed to the db also, but the user only wants to change (and save) the language and not to save the data he has changed before.

So my question is: How can I just save the changed user-object without saving other changes in the current user conversation.

I'm using JBoss with JSF, Primefaces, Hibernate, Seam-Transactions and long running conversations.

Comment: Are you using a merge type operation, if so, why not just send the object id and the new language to a method to look up the entity, set the language and commit rather than the full entity and all its changes?

Comment: Can you explain this in a short example? How should the update method look like?

Comment: This is the current update method:

`@Transactional
    public void changeUserLocale(String username, Locale newLocale) {
        User user = findUserByUsername(username);
        user.setUserLocale(newLocale);

        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }`